# Able to echo variable but unable to substitute value in java shell command

Tags: shell-script, variable, echo, variable-substitution

I am trying to read some variable (username and password) from config file and use them with java command:-

**abc.config**

```
user_id=myid  
user_password=mypassword  
jar=/home/abc.jar
```

Now I am executing :-

```
.  /home/abc.config;
echo $user_id;  
echo $user_password;  
java -jar $jar -u $user_id -p $user_password;
```

After execution getting o/p :-

```
myid  
mypassword  
java -jar $jar -u $user_id -p $user_password;
```

My problem is if I can echo variables then what I am doing wrong when using it in combination with java command.

Comment: How did you determine that you are getting the result shown in the `java -jar` command?

Comment: @steeldriver I ahave updated My config thanks for comment

Comment: "After execution getting o/p :-": after executing _what_? What commands are you running? How are you getting the output `java -jar $jar -u $user_id -p $user_password;`?

Comment: My point is that when I am executing  .  /home/abc.config;  
echo $user_id;    
echo $user_password;    
java -jar $jar -u $user_id -p $user_password;    I can echo all variables in config file but not able to substitute them actually in java command

Comment: What is the symptom of this failure? Do you get error messages? I notice that you're not quoting the expansion of any variable, this may cause the shell to split their values on whitespace and to apply filename globbing to them.

Comment: Not getting any error Just it is not replacing the $jar   $username  $password Actually I am using all steps in airflow bash operator.In that I am specifying        ''' .  /home/abc.config;  
echo $user_id;    
echo $user_password;    
java -jar $jar -u $user_id -p $user_password;'''                                                          and I can echo variables  but not able to execute last step mean java - jar .....

Comment: Why does the `java` execution show up in the output (last block in the Q), there is nothing in the commands you run which should cause this? But assuming the shell commands are ok, could the problem be on the Java side (meaning you have a bug in reading the arguments)?

Comment: @nohillside but when I pass mypassword instead of  $password it works.Even I am not able to get $jar value

Comment: What is the output if you run `echo java -jar $jar -u $user_id -p $user_password`?

Comment: Use `set -x` (or your shell's equivalent) before the command to see what the shell is *actually* passing

Comment: thanks @nohillside its actually adding newline after each value.But how can I stop this adding newline?

Comment: Make sure to create `abc.config` on a Unix system, not on Windows :-)

Comment: @nohillside thanks Creating file on Unix solved my problem